# Give an example of a faithful representation of $D_8$ of degree 3.

Tags: representation-theory

Give an example of a faithful representation of $D_8$ of degree 3.

So $D_8$=<$a,b : a^4=b^2=1, ab=ba^{-1}$>.

A representation is faithful if ker(p)=e.

The solution to this question i am given is that

$$a->\begin{matrix}0 & -1 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\end{matrix}$$

and

$$b->\begin{matrix}1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & -1 & 0\\0 & 0 & -1\end{matrix}$$

but I have absolutely no idea where this has come from.

Thanks

Comment: You should probably have $ab=ba^{-1}$ as one of the relations, and the other matrix should be representing $b$, not $a$.

Comment: Anyway, this 3-dimensional representation looks like a direct sum of the "defining" 2-dimensional representation and a 1-dimensional representation gotten by taking the determinant of that defining rep. As that 2-dimensional component is already faithful, so is this.

Comment: yes sorry that was a typo

Comment: could you explain a bit more where the matrices come from